# Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I am working through a javascript problem that asks me to:

Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array.

For example, the input

```
chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
```

should return the 'chunked arrays':
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]

I can get it to work for most examples but when there are more than 2 chunks it switches the order and I am not sure why. Here is the code that I have written:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArray = [],
      i, temp = arr;
  for (i = 0;i<= arr.length-size;i+=size){
    newArray.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    temp.splice(i,size);
  }
  newArray.push(temp);
  return newArray;
}
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another version:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var result = [];
    while (arr.length > size) {
        result.push(arr.splice(0, size))
    }
    if (arr.length)
        result.push(arr);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was working on this problem too, and now I see this code, and it works, but I still don't understand it, can somebody explain this to me? We have size = 2, and, arr.splice(0, 2) gives us only ['a', 'b'], what next?

Comment: What do you mean - what next?

Comment: @u_mulder, we get this result:  [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], but the while loop doesn't have ++ at the end that allows code to be executed repeatedly. I'm confused here. I don't even know how to express my self.

Comment: There's no need to add `++` As soon as you `splice` array, array reduces.

Comment: @u_mulder, oh, all right! Now I understand, thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = []; // New empty array
  while (arr.length > 0) { // Loop thru the array items
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size)); // Removes first 2 items then add it to new array
  }
  return newArr; // New 2D array
}
```

I tried using these lines of codes in console and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are both advancing `i` by `size` at each iteration and removing `size` elements from position `i`. This causes you to skip processing every other chunk. Also, your continuation condition should be `i < arr.length-size`; as it is, you would need to test for an empty `temp` before pushing it after the loop exits. Try rewriting your loop as:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length-size;){
    newArray.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    temp.splice(i,size);
}
```

Since `i` is always at 0, the loop can be simplified to:

```
while (arr.length > size) {
    newArray.push(arr.slice(0,size));
    temp.splice(0,size);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this loop run forever though if 'i' doesn't iterate?

Comment: @Gwen - No, because each time through the loop, `arr.length` goes down by `size`. Eventually, `arr.length - size` will be less than `i` (which is always 0). (Now that I think about it, since `i` stays at 0, it could be eliminated from the loop. I'll rewrite the loop to show that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  // x is less than or equals arr.length.
  for(var x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++){
     newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }

  if (arr.length){
     newArr.push(arr);
  }
  return newArr;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of the code. only code is not enough. Also explain why is your answer better than the accepted answer(if that's the case)

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {

  var arr1=[];
  var j=0,temp=size;
  var len = arr.length/size;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    arr1.push(arr.slice(j,size));
    j+=temp;
    size+=temp;
  }
  return arr1;
}

chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
```

Comment: Another Simple answer to the question. Though its not the fastest in execution. Just divide the total array length with the required size to get the total number of iterations & thus this problem can also b solved without using splice !!

Comment: Move your comment into the answer, please

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var acum=[];
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i=i+size)
  {
    var vec=arr.slice(i,size+i);
    acum.push(vec);
  }

  return acum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So many Ways...

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
 var value = [];

for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i += size){
 value.push(arr.slice(i, size+i));
}

return value;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var result = [],
      iterations = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);
  for (var i =0; i<iterations;i++){
      var sub = arr.splice(0, size);
      result.push(sub);
  }
  return result;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

  var temp = [];
  var result = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (a % size !== size - 1)
      temp.push(arr[a]);
    else {
      temp.push(arr[a]);
      result.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }
  }

  if (temp.length !== 0)
    result.push(temp);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newarr=[];
  var num=0;
  var szie=0;
  var size2=size;
  if(arr.length%size==0){
    szie=arr.length/size;
  }
  else{
    var floor=arr.length/size;
    szie=Math.floor(floor)+1;
  }
  for (let i=0;i<szie;i++){
      newarr.push(arr.slice(num,size));
      num=num+size2;
      size=size+size2;

  }
  return newarr;
}
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).